# how to include category id in url on category page?

Tags: url-rewrite, seo, magento-2.1.3, category-listing, category-id

I have one query regarding category id.I need to include category id, in category list page. Currently it should be like this :

http://magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags/backpacks

I want to show like this :

http://magento2.shelltag.com/women/bags/backpacks-6

How can it be achieved?

[image]

is this is the possible solution?

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry(‌​'current_product'); $categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/ foreach($categories as $category){ $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->lo‌​ad($category); echo $cat->getId(); } ?>
```

or in which file i need to make changes?

Comment: Is this is the possible solution?
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    echo $cat->getId();
    }

?>
or in which file i need to make changes?

Comment: do i need to call observer class or how to do it?

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: any idea regarding the same?